# Alphabetical order in array with multiple defaults on top

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array with strings and i would like it on alphabetical order but with some defaults on top. For example:

```
["a", "b", "default1", "d", "default2", "c", "e"]
```

and I would like the result to be:

```
["default1", "default2", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

somebody has an idea how I can accomplish this easy?

UPDATE

The defaults are also included in the array and the array is in alphabetical order.

Comment: Are the defaults things you add explicitly, or are they included in the array, and you want to force them to the top?

Comment: is the input array pre-ordered? if not, are the default values ordered alphabetically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enumerable includes [`partition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
data = ["a", "b", "default1", "d", "default2", "c", "e"]
data.partition{ |d| d['default'] }.flatten
=> ["default1", "default2", "a", "b", "d", "c", "e"]
```

If the data you get isn't sorted into the final order you want, you can pre-sort it before partitioning it:

```
data = ["c", "b", "default2", "a", "default1", "e", "d"]
data.sort.partition{ |d| d['default'] }.flatten
=> ["default1", "default2", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

If you need a more intelligent and comprehensive sorting algorithm, to handle various "default" entries, you could probably use `sort` or `sort_by` with a lambda or proc that can tell the difference between the defaults and regular entries, and return the required `-1`, `0` and `1` values.

Comment: Nice answer, you can test for pretty much anything to build the partition, easy to read!

Comment: Using `partition` is a nice solution, the only problem would be if -in the second case- the desired default values are not alphabetically ordered (the question does not specify it). A very minor nit-picking: I'd write `flatten(1)` to make clear that I want a one-level flattening to de-structure the partition (IMHO it's unfortunate that `flatten` is recursive by default).

Comment: The OP's question doesn't specify a lot of things that are important. I agree that flatten shouldn't be recursive. Since, for this question, the result of `partition` is a limited depth array of arrays, `flatten` without a parameter is safe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is an awesome solution and I did not know that partition exists.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this works :

```
array = ["a", "b", "default1", "d", "default2", "c", "e"]
defaults = ["default1", "default2"] #Add more if needed
sorted_array = array.sort{|a, b| defaults.include?(a) ? -1 : defaults.include?(b) ? 1 : a <=> b }
puts sorted_array # => ["default1", "default2", "a", "b" "c", "d", "e"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I think The Thin Man's solution is a little cleaner but this is also a very good solution. Can only accept one :( Going to specify my question a little better

Answer (score 3):

Taking advantage of the lexicographical order defined by an array, I'd write:

```
defaults = Hash[["default1", "default2"].to_enum.with_index.to_a]
xs = ["a", "b", "default1", "d", "default2", "c", "e"]
xs.sort_by { |x| [defaults[x] || defaults.size, x] }
#=> ["default1", "default2", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```